# How do I find which Pivot Tables has an error in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm receiving an error:

> `cannot open PivotTable source file ...XLSX SHEET...`

while refreshing all data. I have many Pivot Tables, and I can't find that one with the error, while refreshing separately – there are no errors, no hidden sheets.

How can I know where the problem is?

Comment: for now, deleted one by one sheets from workbook (copy), until refresh all works.

Comment: Did the error message specify a sheet number?

Have you tried saving as xlsb and then back to the original format? Sometimes that fixed some corruption issues for me.

Comment: 1. no sheet number specified by error message.
2. didn't try, but I think wouldn't help, because there was a problem with one of pivot, found it by deleting sheets one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a complex spreadsheet. I deleted all tabs until I had a blank tab, and I still recievedc this message. I found that the underlying PowerPivot data model referenced a linked table that no longer existed. Deleting the linked table in the PowerPivot model resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check VBA Code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947/how-can-i-refresh-all-the-pivot-tables-in-my-excel-workbook-with-a-macro). I modified it. If you run the code it will break if any error occurs.

```
Public Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet, Pivot As PivotTable
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
        Debug.Print Sheet.name & "-->" & Pivot.name
        Pivot.RefreshTable
        Pivot.Update
    Next
Next
End Sub
```